# Not able to connect to springboot websocket @MessageMapping url

Tags: spring-boot, react-native, spring-websocket

I am practicing websocket with springboot and followed the guide and made some changes on my own.
My react native application is able to connect to websocket but it sending a message to the endpoint doesn't do anything.

I even tried with postman but it doesn't work.

**My WebSocketConfig:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebSocketMessageBroker
public class WebSocketConfig implements WebSocketMessageBrokerConfigurer {

    @Override
    public void registerStompEndpoints(StompEndpointRegistry registry) {
        registry.addEndpoint("/ws")
                .setAllowedOriginPatterns("*");
    }

    @Override
    public void configureMessageBroker(MessageBrokerRegistry registry) {
        registry.setApplicationDestinationPrefixes("/app");
        registry.enableSimpleBroker("/queue");
    }
}
```

**WebSocketController:**

```
@Controller
public class WebSocketController {

    private final SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate;
    private final Map<String, WebSocketSession> userSessions;
    private final MiqaatService miqaatService;

    public WebSocketController(SimpMessagingTemplate messagingTemplate, MiqaatService miqaatService) {
        this.messagingTemplate = messagingTemplate;
        this.miqaatService = miqaatService;
        this.userSessions = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();
    }

    @MessageMapping("/miqaat")
    public void getMiqaats(Principal principal, WebSocketSession session) {

        String userId = principal.getName();
        List<MiqaatDto> miqaats = miqaatService.getAllMiqaatByUserArea(userId);

        userSessions.put(userId, session);

        messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(userId, "/queue/miqaats", miqaats);
    }

    @EventListener
    public void handleWebSocketDisconnectListener(SessionDisconnectEvent event) {
        String userId = Objects.requireNonNull(event.getUser()).getName();
        userSessions.remove(userId);
    }

    public void sendUpdatedRecords(List<MiqaatDto> updatedRecords, List<User> userIds) {
        userIds.forEach(user -> {
            WebSocketSession session = userSessions.get(user.getId().toString());
            if (session != null && session.isOpen()) {
                messagingTemplate.convertAndSendToUser(user.getId().toString(), "/queue/miqaats", updatedRecords);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**React Native code:**

```
  const [socket, setSocket] = useState(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    const token = user.authToken;
    const headers = {
      Authorization: `${token}`,
    };

    const ws = new WebSocket("ws://192.168.0.100:8080/ws", "", { headers });

    ws.onopen = () => {
      console.log("WebSocket connection opened");

      const message = {
        destination: '/app/miqaat',
        headers: {
          // Add any additional headers if required
        },
        payload: '',
      };
    ws.send(JSON.stringify(message));
    };

    ws.onmessage = (event) => {
      const receivedData = event.data;
      const receivedRecords = JSON.parse(receivedData);
      setRecords(receivedRecords);
      console.log("records", records);
    };

    ws.onerror = (error) => {
      console.error("WebSocket error:", error);
    };

    setSocket(ws);
    return () => ws.close()
  }, []);
```